# How can I set environment variables and functions that are available to sh -c?

Tags: terminal

I'm on Monterey, using zsh, and I'm wondering trying to find a place to define variables and functions that will be made available to a standard, vanilla, non-interactive, non-login, non-zsh shells such as:

- `sh -c 'echo $MY_GLOBAL_VAR'`
- `sh -c 'echo $(my_global_function)'`

I've seen many historical ways to handle this that seem to be broken in the latest versions of MacOS.

Is there a recommended approach to this?

Comment: What exactly have you tried, what exactly do you want to accomplish once you have it working?  `foo=bar sh -c 'echo $foo'` or `export foo=bar; sh -c 'echo $foo'` should work also with `zsh`, passing shell functions most likely won't.

Comment: I use other tools, such as `yabai` which execute scripts when certain commands are run. I get to define the script, but not the shell it runs them in (it runs them with `sh -c`) so my zsh environment configuration is not available to them.

I want to be able to define env vars and functions that are available to those scripts, as well as my own scripts that I run in interactive zsh sessions.

Comment: So far, I've tried exporting vars in `/etc/profile` (doesn't work) and right now I'm exploring setting vars in `launchd`, but that seems a bit overkill.

Comment: It might help to add the relevant context to the question to get useful answers. Running scripts through `yabai` is different than running them from a shell, `yabai` doesn't even know that you are running `zsh`.

Comment: I probably would define all the variables/functions which I need everywhere in `~/.local/etc/master.profile` and then source it from all scripts which need it.